# SQL Server identity column error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am using SQL Server 2012. When I make an `identity` column which starts from 1 and increases by 1 on
each insert but suddenly me identity increases from a huge margin

[image]

Comment: This can only happen, if you have deleted many rows recently.

Comment: yup i deleted many rows. . but whether is there any solution of it?

Comment: @Asad Jivani - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/reset-identity-column-value-in-sql-server/

Comment: @iCobot well I know how to reseed an identity but i am asking the solution of this error ?Is it a bug?

Comment: If you've deleted many rows, it's logical that the missing identity values are those that belonged to the deleted rows. The point is, what is the problem you're searching a solution for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only happen, if you have deleted many rows recently and so your `IDENTITY` column will start from the last seed value. Yes, you can reseed the identity column using `DBCC` command utility like below but that's unnecessary. Let, the identity column increase in it's normal way and you shouldn't be much worried about that.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', RESEED, 25);
```

Comment: Ok..but is there any Solution of this error?except to reseed an identity column

Comment: NO, reseeding is the way but that's really not needed. Moreover, jump on identity value shouldn't bother you much ... let it grow in it's usual space.